# Links in an external program

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, permalinks

I have a software in which the helppages are included as HTML inside the program itself. It's some kind of Internet explorer in my software. Now I wanted to add video links to some YouTube tutorials about my software.

```
<a href="my-YT-Link" target="blank">Name of the video</a>
```

But when I press the link on the help page it justs opens another IE tab inside my software.

My goal is it, that the link will be opened in the default browser of the user, and not inside my software.

Is that possible?